# Cannot set size of window in appleScript

Tags: macos, applescript

Hy,

I'm writting a script which have to set position and size of a windows.

The application which i need to resize is an AIR application.

The set position is ok, but the set size do nothing.

I have simplify the script for this example :

```
tell application "System Events" to tell application process "adl"  
    display dialog (get name of window 1)  
    set position of window 1 to {50, 50}    
    set size of window 1 to {100, 100}  
end tell
```

Could you help me?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

You can change the `position` of the window, but not the `size`.

Reasons :

1- This window has constraints on its size (minimum, maximum or both), so you can not resize lower or higher than these constraints.

2- This window has a defined size, so no zoom.

Comment: thanks, but can I add parameters to my Adobe Air compilator for allow appleScript to set the size?

Comment: You need to adjust the properties (`maxSize, minSize, maximizable, minimizable, resizable`) before creating the window.
As I do not know this program, I found this as an example --> 
 


var opts:NativeWindowInitOptions = new NativeWindowInitOptions();
opts.minimizable = true;
opts.maximizable = true;
opts.resizable = true;
options.systemChrome = NativeWindowSystemChrome.STANDARD;
options.transparent = false;
options.type = NativeWindowType.NORMAL;
var window:NativeWindow = new NativeWindow(options);
window.minSize = new Point(40,40);
window.activate();

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: My original comment was incorrect and thus removed to not confuse anyone. The following script indeed shows a window of a process has size and position properties.

```
tell application "System Events"
    tell process "Safari"
        properties of window 1
    end tell
end tell
```

Comment: His script works at least for the `position`.
The `bounds` property of the window is in the "**Standard suite**", useless for the "System Events" application (no window) . 

A window in "**Processes Suite**" is a `ui element`, therefore it has the same properties as a `ui element` (`position, size, ...`).

Answer (score 0):

This code works for native `macOS` applications and resizes the window to full screen.

```
tell application "Finder"
    set maximum_size to bounds of window of desktop
end tell

tell application "Terminal"
    set the bounds of the first window to maximum_size
    activate
end tell
```

I don't know about AIR. Source [here](https://www.labnol.org/software/resize-mac-windows-to-specific-size/28345/).